# MapView animate to point problem

Tags: android, animation, popup, android-mapview

I have a following problem.

I have a mapView with custom overlays which show popups. Popups appear properly.

The issue is that when i zoom in with zoomButtons and I tap an overlay it animates to a tottaly different place.

What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're changing the position in onTap or onTouchEvent of your custom ItemizedOverlay